# How do I configure PerlSections in mod_perl2?

Tags: perl, apache2, mod-perl2, perlsections

I'm trying to use a `[PerlSection][1]` to get the server name and then use it to configure some `RewriteCond`-`RewriteRule` pairs and some other things.  It seems I can't get very far.  It says you can do this:

```
Apache2->httpd_conf("PerlPassEnv $key $val");
```

But trying to start Apache I get this syntax error:

```
"Can't locate object method "httpd_conf" via package "Apache2"
```

The docs then refer to these two files I can supposedly find in the distribution, eg/httpd.conf.pl and eg/perl_sections.txt, but [the mod_perl2 distribution](http://perl.apache.org/dist/mod_perl-2.0-current/) doesn't even have an *eg* dir, and the original mod_perl's eg dir doesn't have either of those files either.

Google was no help either, for "Your search - perl_sections.txt site:http://perl.apache.org/dist/ - did not match any documents" and without the site restriction all I see, besides the docs, is one post asking about these files copied all over with no answer.

Anybody have any resources for how to actually use a <Perl> section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel your pain. I used the docs to produce some educated guesses for my trial and error process. What finally worked was pushing all configuration item onto the `@PerlConfig` array. Here's an example from my answer to a [completely different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88570/can-regex-capture-and-substitution-be-used-with-an-apache-directorymatch-directiv/91535#91535):

```
<Perl>
my @groups = qw/ foo bar baz /;
foreach ( @groups ) {
    push @PerlConfig, qq| <Directory /home/www/$_> blah </Directory> |;
}
</Perl>
```

Comment: Oh, okay, that part of the docs is actually true.  I had tried the $ServerName they refer to and was beginning to assume it was fabricated... ;)

Comment: sorry for bringing up the dead, but I am new to perl and im trying to get this thing working... i am getting this exact error but I do not understand what I am meant to do. its all new to me I dont want to break anything. could you direct me into what the problem is so i can search abit more?